# Get aggregate with lookup in single Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my problem is how I get a simple object of ownerDetails, correct me if my code is wrong

data I got, from my code

```
    {
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "61a2a9680b122bc154cbd6af",
            "ownerName": "Ajay",
            "mobile": 878787878,
            "designation": "IT",
            "gender": "Male",
            "age": 26,
            "carDetails": [
                {
                    "carName": "BUY",
                    "color": "blue",
                    "sheets": 8,
                    "avgSpeed": 105,
                    "price": 850000,
                    "model": "C110"
                },
                {
                    "carName": "GTR",
                    "color": "blue",
                    "sheets": 4,
                    "avgSpeed": 105,
                    "price": 98000,
                    "model": "G120"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i want data like this,

```
    {
    "status": true,
    "ownerDetails":  {
            "_id": "61a2a9680b122bc154cbd6af",
            "ownerName": "Ajay",
            "mobile": 878787878,
            "designation": "IT",
            "gender": "Male",
            "age": 26,
            "total_car": 2,
        }
}
```

code for getting data from collections

```
    exports.getOwnerDetails = async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    Owner.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { ownerName: req.body.ownerName }
      },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "cars",
          localField: "ownerName",
          foreignField: "ownerName",
          as: "carDetails",
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          "carDetails._id": 0,
          "carDetails.ownerName": 0,
        },
      },
    ]).then((data) => {
      res.json({
        status: true,
        data: data,
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: false,
      msg: "Error : " + error,
    });
  }
};
```

in may returning data, I got an array of carDetails, but I only need that how many are owned by an Owner, and return a simple object of ownerDetails

Comment: data is array with possible many owners, you just want the first owner only?Or you always have only 1?

Comment: how many cars are owned by an owner(not car details), if an owner owns 2 cars, just return a "total_cars": 2,

Comment: you got both solutions i think you will be ok, but it helps to know if a document has more fields or if an array has more members and what you want to do with those.

Answer (score 3):

`$lookup` return an array because more than one values can match the join. If you want to get only one value you can get the first element from the array. Then you can add these aggregation stages:

- First `$addFields` to get the first element from the array (index 0).
- Then use `$project` to get the desired output.

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "data": {
      "$arrayElemAt": ["$data",0]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "status": 1,
    "ownerDetails": {
      "_id": "$data._id",
      "ownerName": "$data.ownerName",
      "mobile": "$data.mobile",
      "designation": "$data.designation",
      "gender": "$data.gender",
      "age": "$data.age",
      "total_car": {
        "$size": "$data.carDetails"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ygBKDeaT1NW)

Answer (score 2):

Query

- i am not sure if this is what you want
- unwind all owners from data
- and from each owner, count its cars number

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70139296-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": {"path": "$data"}},
 {"$set": 
   {"data.total_car": {"$size": "$data.carDetails"},
    "data.carDetails": "$$REMOVE",
    "_id": "$$REMOVE"}},
 {"$set": {"ownerDetails": "$data", "data": "$$REMOVE"}}])
```